# Why QgsFeature.geometry() returns an empty geometry in PyQGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, geometry, features, pyqgis-3

I am a new for QGIS, working in Python.

I add a buildings(.shp) vector layer into QGIS, just like this:

[image]

I'd like to get the geometrys of some features, then I can do analysis on the center point.

But when I use API `geometry()`, it returns me a empty geometry and I cannot get the center point. When I tried `.hasGeometry()`, it returns me a False.

My code is following:

```
path = '/Users/vctcn93/Desktop/export/canton.shp'

def SelectRange(px1, py1, px2, py2):

    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

    p1 = QgsPointXY(px1, py1)
    p2 = QgsPointXY(px2, py2)
    rec = QgsRectangle(p1,p2)

    layer.selectByRect(rec, 0)

    ids = layer.selectedFeatureIds()
    features = [QgsFeature(id) for id in ids]

    return features, rec, layer
    #retruns list<QgsFeature>,QgisRectangle,QgisVectorLayer 

def SelectFea(features, rectangle):
    for a in features:
        geometry = a.geometry()#here returns me a empty geometry
        bbx = geometry.boundingBox()

        if bbx.xMaximum() >= rectangle.xMaximum() \
        or bbx.yMinimum() <= rectangle.yMinimum():
            features.remove(a)

    return features
```

Please help me on this problem, I tried a lot but cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [getSelectedFeatures](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a89189517ec26fb835739e9e5e4f7bf46):

> Returns an iterator of the selected features.

Example:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByRect(QgsRectangle(QgsPointXY(405265,6457186),QgsPointXY(409286,6463306)))
features = [f for f in layer.getSelectedFeatures()]
```